# How do I resolve Exception from MVC App where datamodel contains 2 FK relationships to same table, using EF6?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developing an Web application using C#/MVC and EF6. I am using the Database First approach, as I am attaching to an existing database (SQL Server 2008-R2).

I have one table that contains 2 foreign keys to the same target as follows:

```
Table Artifact:
    int ArtifactId;
    int AnalystId;  //Employee performing analysis work on artifact
    int ChampionId; //Employee servind as champion for artifact
```

And the target table is very straightforward.

```
Table Employee:
    int EmployeeId;
    // Employee info
```

I managing the Datbase access as a disconnected repository so that when I retrieve and update the information, I can manage the state.

```
    public Candidate GetArtifact(int artifactId)
    {
        using (var context = new DataEntities())
        {
            return context.Artifacts.AsNoTracking()
                .Where(x => x.ArtifactId == artifactId)
                .Include(x => x.Employee)         //Analyst
                .Include(x => x.Employee1)        //Champion
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public int SaveArtifact(Artifact artifact)
    {
        using (var context = new DataEntities())
        {
            if (artifact.ArtifactId > 0)
            {
                context.Entry(artifact).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            else
            {
                context.Artifacts.Add(artifact);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
            return artifact.CandidateId;
        }
    }
```

Everything works as I would expect, except for the case where both the Analyst and the Champion reference the same record from the Employee record. In testing the update existing code path, I get one of 2 exceptions, depending on the initial state of the data. Note, the exception only happens when the data is updated, it retrieves correctly without issue.

When I attempt to update an artifact with both the Analyst and Champion referencing the same employee record. I get the following exception:

```
Attaching an entity of type 'Data.DataModel.Employee' failed because another
entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can
happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to
'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key
values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received
database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the
'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new
entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.
```

Any suggestions on what I can do to correct this?

Comment: Where `candidateRecord` comes from? If it is a query result(s), that's obviously triggering exception since you can't have multiple entity/type loaded with same name and primary key when updating context.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the Candidate reference. That was a cut/paste error in the question, and I have updated to clarify the actual reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a little additional digging, I found the solution to my particular problem.  The pattern that I was following (established by one of my colleagues) was to eager load all data records.  So the Fetch for the artifact included two Include statements to include the 2 different keys, as seen above in my original example.

Where this caused a problem is that, in the case where both the Champion and Analyst were referencing the same Employee record, the update saw the primary key/record from the Analyst already attached to context, so threw the exception when it attempted to attach what was actually the same record to the context again for the Champion.

My solution was to remove the eager loading from the retrieval, which for my particular design imposed no real issues since the Employee record is really referential only and never updated in conjunction with the artifact update.

so my GetArtifact method looks like the following after the fix:

```
public Candidate GetArtifact(int artifactId)
{
    using (var context = new DataEntities())
    {
        return context.Artifacts.AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.ArtifactId == artifactId)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

And the couple of places that actually reference the Employee record just use the appropriate ID and directly fetches the record.  This prevents the issue.

For me, the lesson learned was to understand Eager Loading and when to use it (and more importantly when NOT to use it).